# loop inside loop over one array

Tags: javascript, performance

I have the following code:

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => i + 1);
const finalArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
       finalArray.push(arr[i] + '-' + arr[j])
   }
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Which creates an array of range 1 => 5, and returns an array with a combination of all elements in the original array.

This code runs in O(n²), is it possible to make it more efficient?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

## No

You cannot output \$\Theta(n^2)\$ items in \$o(n^2)\$ time. Output size is a **trivial lower bound** of any algorithms.

Comment: So you mean that my code is most performant?

Comment: @callback from the view of big-O notation: Yes. To improve its performance: Maybe No.